# AppLovin listeners dont work

Tags: android, applovin

I have integrated `appLovin` in my app and the ads show fine.

The problem is that i `dont receive any callbacks` from their listeners

Sample code:

```
AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(m_context.getApplicationContext());
    sdk = AppLovinSdk.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());
    adDialog = AppLovinInterstitialAd.create(sdk, (Activity) m_context);
    adDialog.setAdDisplayListener(new AppLovinAdDisplayListener() {
        @Override
        public void adDisplayed(AppLovinAd appLovinAd) {
            Log.d(OutbidManager.TAG, "adDisplayed apploving");
        }

        @Override
        public void adHidden(AppLovinAd appLovinAd) {
            Log.d(OutbidManager.TAG, "adHidden apploving");
        }
    });
    adDialog.setAdLoadListener(new AppLovinAdLoadListener() {
        @Override
        public void adReceived(AppLovinAd appLovinAd) {
            Log.d(OutbidManager.TAG, "adReceived apploving");
        }

        @Override
        public void failedToReceiveAd(int i) {
            Log.d(OutbidManager.TAG, "failedToReceiveAd apploving");
        }
    });

    adDialog.setAdClickListener(new AppLovinAdClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void adClicked(AppLovinAd appLovinAd) {
            Log.d(OutbidManager.TAG, "adClicked apploving");
        }
    });
```

For showing the ad i use:

```
   if(adDialog.isAdReadyToDisplay())
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Displaying applovin");
                adDialog.show();
            }
```

Comment: are you sure that is not caused by setting a wrong Log filter in logcat?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you're showing the ad?  Also, did you mean to have both context and m_context variables?

Comment: i added the code for displaying the ad, i am displaying the ad in a non activity class thats why i am casting the context to activity. m_context and context are same

Comment: Did you get is solved?